# take two column data and populate into a third column the highest value

Tags: vlookup

I am trying to get excel to populate data into a 4th column using the values in 3 columns:
So

```
  A         B         C          D 
8500       9000      8750       ???
```

i want a formula that will put the highest value into D

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in column D

```
=MAX(A1, B1, C1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the Formula to the cell D

```
=MAX ( A1,B1,C1)
```

[image]